# vim autoindent buffer on enter & exit

Tags: vim

For writable buffers, is there a way to tell vim to autoindent a file on entering & exiting the buffer?

What I want is the equiv of:

```
1G=G

to go first line
indent ..
until last line
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use autocommands (`:h :au`), for example `BufRead` and maybe `BufWritePre`.